# Postprocessing PDF presentations

Tags: pdf, presentations

Few years ago I had been successfully using [`ppower4`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ppower4) for PDF postprocessing.  It seems that it is no longer maintained, do you know a good replacement for this?

Comment: For what do you need it exactly? It seems to be used for presentations, so [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) would be a good replacement. It allows dynamic effects out-of-the-box without any post-processing required.

Comment: Thank you Martin - a good answer for incorrect question.

Comment: @Martin: Want to make an answer out of that comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ppower4` seems to be used for presentations, so [`beamer`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/beamer) would be a good replacement. It allows dynamic effects out-of-the-box without any post-processing required